# How to reference a cell in a different file

Tags: google-sheets, importrange

I have two separate Google Sheets files ("File A" and "File B") that are in two different places in my Google drive.

Is it possible for me to reference a range of cells in "File A" to be copied into "File B"?

From what I've seen, the built in function IMPORTRANGE only works to reference information from a different sheet within the same file and does not work for inter-file communication... unless there is some cool voodoo stuff that can be done.

Answer (score 1):

From [IMPORTRANGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en)

> Imports a range of cells from a specified spreadsheet.

The above means that if you add it correctly to a cell in File B it could import data from File A.

It's worth to say that in this site there are 180 [questions and answers](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-spreadsheets%5D%20importrange) about [google-spreadsheets](/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheets) and IMPORTRANGE at this time.